# Comparing two DOM elements in javascript (the proper way)?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following js code:

```
changeVideo(element) {
  const currentVideo = document.querySelector('.current-video');
  const nextVideo = document.querySelector(`${element}`);
  if (currentVideo === nextVideo) {
    return;
  }
  // more code here
}
```

Is this the correct/proper way to compare DOM Elements?
(currentVideo === nextVideo)

The expectation is for this to work in all modern browsers.

Comment: Sure, you can do that. (though, no need for the template literal, just pass `element`. better to name it `selectorString` or something though). I'd prefer to use `nextVideo.matches('.current-video')` though

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are, for example, trying to find out if two different `<video>` elements have the same `src` attribute value, then no.

Comment: @CertainPerformance — query strings belong in URLs, it is a selector.

Comment: This will check if the two elements are literally the same node. If that's what you want then, yes, that's correct.

Comment: looks good. nothing wrong in it. what part of the code is bothering you ? are you worried about browser compatibility ?

Comment: @Quentin if I'm trying to find out if the two different <video> elements have the same src attribute (and they do in a specific case) , what will be the proper way than ? (Btw the video tag does not have src attribute it the source tag has it )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess after almost 2 years the problem has been solved... but for future searches, you can use  **Node.isEqualNode()** for more information go to [MDN on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isEqualNode)